# React router V5 updating URL but not refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

react router is not updating the view but changes the url.

Navbar.js:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../Assets/imgs/Logo/WHITELOGOkatman 1.png";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
class Navbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="logo" />
        <Router>
          <nav>
            <ul className="nav_links">
              <Link to="/">
                <li>Home</li>
              </Link>
              <Link to="/process">
                <li>Process</li>
              </Link>
              <Link to="/career">
                <li>Career</li>
              </Link>
              <Link to="/about">
                <li>About</li>
              </Link>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Navbar;
```

And this is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "./Components/Styles/style.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import About from "./Components/About";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import Career from "./Components/Career";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer";
import notFoundPage from "./Components/404";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/career" component={Career} />
          <Route path="/notfound" component={notFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What I have tried:

1. I have tried exporting all the components I am rendering inside of a Router with withRouter. still the page did not reload.
2. I have tried making the router component a top level component but that did not work.
3. I have tried making the li items as links, but that did not do what I want.
4. I have tried soltuions like including a switch on top of the link tags, and removing the switch from the router tag but still nothing worked.
5. I have also tried switching the order of the routes to make the home at the end of the routes. Still nothing.

Comment: could you maybe make a CodeSandBox or something like that for this question? a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: PLUS 1 for the question. I remember I have experienced this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try these two things:

- First ensure that the ordering of your Route is as follows:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/career" component={Career} />
  <Route path="/notfound" component={notFoundPage} />
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

- Remove `<Router>` inside your `<Nav>` and wrap everything inside `<App>` with `<Router>`... Like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/career" component={Career} />
            <Route path="/notfound" component={notFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I think it's worth noting that in my experience I've come to realize that `<Router>` expects only 1 child. so in your case you used `<Router>` twice.

---

I might also want to simplify it further by putting your `<Router>` in index.js file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Router>
      <App />
   </Router>,
   containerElement
);
```

Comment: And it's not throwing any error? can you inspect console and see if there's any errors?

Comment: no errors whatsoever. not even a warning regarding this at all..

Comment: That's strange. Can you please try the suggest above. I've just added something that i think might be the case, since there's no error I'm kinda suggesting some normal ways we often approach this.

Comment: YES!! That worked but why? How come I am using <Link> tag without a router enclosing it?

Comment: Remember `<Nav>` will be used inside `<App>` which is wrapped in `<Router>`.. so in the end, everything that is used inside `<App>` has access to `<Router>`